# extending the scope of sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

It is OK to use `sudo` on a single command to run it with superuser privileges:

```
sudo echo "hi"
```

But when I use pipes with the command:

```
sudo echo "hi" > /a.txt
```

The superuser privilege does not extend to the pipe (`> /a.txt`) part, and I get an error for denied permission:

> bash: /a.txt: Permission denied

My question is:

Is there a syntax in which I can extend the scope of `sudo` in above to also work on the pipeline part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the command in a root-elevated shell and then your I/O redirection will also be done as root:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "hi" > /a.txt'
```

If you don't want to create a subshell to do this, here's a workaround with `tee`:

```
echo "hi" | sudo tee /a.txt > /dev/null
```

---

### Additional Resources:

- [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82256/1038828)
  on Stack Overflow